# Spree Commerce Shipping Calculators Not Found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, rails-console

I am trying to add a Shipping Method to my install (first time adding a shipping method). When I visit this form (`admin/shipping_methods/new`), there are no shipping calculators available under the Calculator drop down. From the documentation, Spree ships with 5 calculators by default, yet there are none available.

I am using Spree `2-4-stable`. I have browsed the repo and sure enough, the calculators are there. I have also researched the controller to see where the call is made to build the calculator array. The code within the controller is:

```
...
@calculators = ShippingMethod.calculators.sort_by(&:name)
...
```

This returns an empty array, hence why no calculators are showing up.

I have tried to pull a list of calculators myself in other areas with no luck.

```
# Returns an empty array as well
@calculators = Spree::ShippingMethod.calculators
```

The odd thing is, if I run `rails console` within my directory and once initialized run

```
# Returns the 5 default calculators
calculators = Spree::ShippingMethod.calculators
```

Naturally, I am confused. Does rails console pull from a different source? How is it I can pull the data from the console, but not the application. No errors, just an empty array from within the application.

This prevents me from adding a shipping method, which prevents me from completing my setup.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this more of a hack than an "answer", but either way, it's a solution.

I finally decided to just create my own Shipping Calculator by simply cloning one of the Spree defaults and renaming it. I followed the documentation for [creating a custom Shipping Calculator](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/calculators.html#creating-a-new-calculator). Once I copied the class and renamed, I added it via the config methods stated.

Upon adding the config statement, all of the default shipping calculators started to appear! As if to create another bug, my custom calculator was no where to be found however. I decided to remove the config line adding my calculator, but left the initial config line which kept the default calculators working.

So, while I am sure this is a bug of some sort, the solution was to add the following line at the bottom of `config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
config = Rails.application.config
```

Restarted the server and boom! Calculators available for selection now.

**UPDATE:**

Just to test, I removed the config line from the file and deleted my custom Shipping Calculator from the directory to see if it would break the Shipping Calculators again. Oddly enough, they still work. Perhaps loading the config using the method above saved a state in the system allowing it to continue functioning.

Either way, I hope someone else out there can provide some light on the issue.